# c# outlook get attachement

Tags: c#, email, outlook, attachment

To decrease mail trafic in the company i'm developing a custom ribbon add-in for outlook.

this should automaticly open files so the receiver of them knows where he must save them. as it is a specific program.

how do i get the 'path' to the documents in a attachement in a specific mail (the one opened by double clicking the mail)?

i aleady got a ribbon with the custom buttons. but can't continue as i need the attachemnts first.

```
private void Ribbon1_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
{

}

private void btnGerbv_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    Forms.MessageBox.Show("Testing");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9e5d89bf-45cd-44b4-ab50-540c6e898721/downloading-attachments-of-outlook-in-c?forum=Vsexpressvcs):

```
private void SaveMailAttachments(Outlook.MailItem mailItem)
{
    Outlook.Attachments attachments = mailItem.Attachments;
    if (attachments != null && attachments.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= attachments.Count; i++)
        {
            Outlook.Attachment attachment = attachments[i];
            if (attachment.Type == Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue)
            {
                string filename = Path.Combine(@"d:\", attachment.FileName);
                attachment.SaveAsFile(filename);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268754.aspx):

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.Application.NewMail += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook
        .ApplicationEvents_11_NewMailEventHandler(ThisApplication_NewMail);
}

private void ThisApplication_NewMail()
{
    Outlook.MAPIFolder inBox = this.Application.ActiveExplorer()
        .Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook
        .OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
    Outlook.Items inBoxItems = inBox.Items;
    Outlook.MailItem newEmail = null;
    inBoxItems = inBoxItems.Restrict("[Unread] = true");
    try
    {
        foreach (object collectionItem in inBoxItems)
        {
            newEmail = collectionItem as Outlook.MailItem;
            if (newEmail != null)
            {
                if (newEmail.Attachments.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 1; i <= newEmail
                        .Attachments.Count; i++)
                    {
                        newEmail.Attachments[i].SaveAsFile
                            (@"C:\TestFileSave\" +
                            newEmail.Attachments[i].FileName);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string errorInfo = (string)ex.Message
            .Substring(0, 11);
        if (errorInfo == "Cannot save")
        {
            MessageBox.Show(@"Create Folder C:\TestFileSave");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this partialy answered my question. 
the problem i'm facing now is that i'm getting all attachemnts from my mailbox. i only need the attachemnts of the opend mail.